# Optimising adapter for multiple inputs

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

In my app, there are many tables, each with different layouts.

So I have made one ListAdapter wherein I pass the context and the list containing data to be displayed.

However, the class is getting complicated due to multiple switch cases.

A normal adapter has `if (convertView == null)`, then we set data and `return convertView`.

But I am having `ViewHolders` for each possible table due to which my `getview` is becoming -

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null){

        // inflate view and link with viewholders...
        switch (num){

        case 1:
            // for table 1
            .
            .
            . 
        case n:
            // for table n
            break;

        }
    }   

    else {

        // set tag for later access
         switch (num) {

         case 1:
            .
            .
            . 
        case n:

        }

    }

    // set VALUES
    switch (num) {

    case 1:
        . 
        . 
        . 
        . 
    case n:

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Needless to say, this is messed up, ugly and doesn't seem efficient.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Use same adapter for each and every listview

Comment: The item of listview has different layout depending on the table. The datasets are also different.

Comment: than inflate different layout in adapter and use viewholder common

Comment: How can there be a common viewholder if the layouts are different!

Comment: define all control in viewholder class and use it as per layout need

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommed using RecyclerView, since it is more efficient. If I understand correctly, you wish to have multiple layouts in one ListView. You can achieve this with ViewTypes in RecyclerView